# Which is memory efficient String or StringBuffer for concatenation in java

Tags: java

I have below Scenario where I am confused to choose between String and StringBuffer

```
final MY_STRING =  VAR1 + "," + VAR2 + "," +VAR3 + ","+..........VAR15;
```

So in this case does *each concatenation* operation will create a *new String object* or after *all the concatenation operations is completed* a *Single String object* is created and assigned to *MY_STRING*.

Or is it memory efficient to do the above operation with *StringBuffer* and convert it to String at last

Comment: use StringBuilder if its async.

Comment: 1) use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`. 2) string concatenation in a single expression is efficient, don't worry about it. 3) try Googling your problem first.

Answer (score 0):

As @Modus Tollens describes in comment. It suggests that the + operator could be implemented using a StringBuffer or a similar technique. So depending on the Java compiler, the + operator is probably already using a StringBuffer (or StringBuilder) internally.

Comment: You keep forgetting that the string + is worked on by the compiler.

Comment: Yes it worked but String is immutable so whenever we put plus it creates new String object.

Comment: Please see [JLS 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1). It suggests that the + operator could be implemented using a StringBuffer or a similar technique. So depending on the Java compiler, the + operator is probably already using a StringBuffer (or StringBuilder) internally.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @ModusTollens Now I got it.